# Can i show Tabs without Action Bar in android 3.0?

Tags: android, tabs

I want to show tab in my fragment but not on Action Bar?
Is this possible, any link or code might help??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [tabWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html).  In a part of my application, I have a `TabActivity` where the inner activity uses fragments. So, it is possible. It may not be the best solution, but I had to do what the customer wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I got the tabs without the rest of the ActionBar by removing the home button and the title, like this:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

and **not** overriding:

```
onCreateOptionsMenu
```

That way the ActionBar would be empty and Android won't display it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of tabs you want to use. In my app I'm using ViewPager together with [indicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) and it works great, so maybe it will suite you. I hope I've understood your question.

Comment: i want to use Tabs but not on Action Bar for my application in android 3.0.

Comment: Well I've I posted you the option that provides you tabs even without action bar, I suppose you haven't even reviewed it.